# How can i connect my custom components on Dashboard to redux store?

Tags: react-admin

I have a Dashboard component './Dashboard' :

```
export default () => (
 <div className="dashboard">
  <ListItems />
  <ItemDetails/>
 </div>
);
```

`ListItems` and `ItemDetails` have some properties. I want to save this properties in inner redux store react-admin.

How can i connect my components `ListItems` and `ItemDetails` to redux store react-admin?

Comment: Hi. React Admin have its own redux store, hidden in its guts.
Would you access to the React Admin store or your custom one?

Comment: Hi ! As I understood, in order to have my own redux store I have to create all custom (https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CustomApp.html), what i do not want to do (now). I want to use react-admin store for storage my custom data.

Comment: In this case, the `customReducers` prop of the `Admin` component is perfect for your use case! https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#customreducers

Comment: @Kmaschta, you're right! Thank you very much for your reply. You can post your comment as an answer to the question, since it really helped me.

Comment: I'll do! But first, can you update your question so it represent your needs more, with an example please?
This way, it will be more helpful for the future readers.